# Pandas merge inside apply having inconsistent behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code (inside a broader code base) which in essence calculates the average buy price for a series of stock trades. The code works as expected except when a float is passed in the price column and it seems to mess up the code. Keen to know what's going on here - doesn't make sense why it works with ints but not floats.
I have isolated the issue to the merge but I'm not sure if that is causing the issue or not.

Code is here: https://repl.it/@gerardsyd/WrathfulSolidEntropy

The code above works perfectly and provides the following output:

```
                Date Ticker  Quantity  Price  Fees Direction   CF  CFBuy  grouping  AvgCostAdj
Ticker
FB     0  24/09/2020     FB        60     10    19       Buy -619   -619       0.0  -10.316667
GOOG   0  02/01/2020   GOOG        10     20    10       Buy -210   -210       0.0  -21.000000
```

If I change the input dataframe's price to floats (as below), the output is incorrect
Make the following change:

```
trades_df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['02/01/2020', 'GOOG', 10, 20.0, 10, 'Buy'],
    ['24/09/2020', 'FB', 60, 10.0, 19, 'Buy'],
    ],
    columns=['Date', 'Ticker', 'Quantity', 'Price', 'Fees', 'Direction'])
```

Which results in the following output:

```
                Date Ticker  Quantity  Price  Fees Direction     CF  CFBuy  grouping  AvgCostAdj
Ticker
FB     0  24/09/2020     FB        60   10.0    19       Buy -619.0 -619.0       0.0  -10.316667
GOOG   0  02/01/2020   GOOG        10   10.0    10       Buy -619.0 -619.0       0.0  -61.900000
```

As you will see, the GOOG avg cost goes to $61.9 which should actually be $21. The issue seems to be around the price changing to $10 and CF changing to -$619.

Interestingly, adding another trade (with prices as floats) fixes the issue. So definitely a very odd edge case.

Scratching my head on this - keen to get some thoughts!

Thanks!

Comment: I ran your code. The results were as follows.`GOOG 0 02/01/2020 GOOG 10 20 10 Buy -210 -210 0.0 -21.000000`

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you run the code as is, it works fine. If you change the price to floats, it stuffs up. See here: https://repl.it/@gerardsyd/QuestionableShyActiveserverpages

Comment: If you try to debug it, you'll see that the output is different before and after the following lines. `df['grouping'] = df['Quantity'].eq(0).shift().cumsum().fillna(0.)`What is this line intended to do?

Comment: Basically that line creates a new column called grouping which groups the stocks based on when the stocks are bought and sold. So let's say 100 shares were bought in Jan and all 100 sold in Feb, that would be group zero. Then if the same stock (ticker) were bought later in the year, it would be group 1. Two things to note, deleting everything but that line, the code works just fine so I don't think that is the issue. And second, in my tests, the problem seems to be with the merge line (deleting that line and everything is fine...)

Comment: But I cannot see where it all goes wrong when I debug it... What I don't understand is why it works with int values in price but not floats. And similarly, why it works when there is more than one trade in each group...

Comment: @r-beginners, I had another play with it and it looks like the line you pointed out was indeed the issue. Changing fillna from (0.) to (0) fixes the problem but it causes the opposite issue (i.e. if its prices are ints, it doesn't work correctly)!
Thanks for the help! Not sure what exactly is causing the issue but it's good enough for me for now!